# Php multiple image upload reduce file size each

Tags: php

How do I compress each image file size and move to upload folder?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the php image resizing libraries use either [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) 
or [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).
If you are using some php framework, you could look for framework specific implementations to make your life easier.

Also, i think this one is worth checking out: https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/php

First 500 image transformations per month are free. And you can resize and optimize(compress) images in the same time. Try manually uploading some images here and see if you are happy with results: https://tinypng.com/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a PHP framework to upload images you can check Cloudinary's API - http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload. From what I understood from their site, with this API you can manipulate and resize images to match your design. Here is another link that I found with two sample projects for demonstrating common Cloudinary's usage in PHP - https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/master/samples